# crystal report 2008 special character in dynamic parameter

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, special-characters, crystal-reports-2008

While working on crystal report 2008, I have created two dynamic parameter, one depending on other, say B is subset of A. A is drop down and B is multiselect box. After selecting A, B get populated. But A have a value having special character, So after selecting same, instead of B getting populated I get a textbox having A selected value and multiselect box get distorted and no values get populated in B. I want B should behave same way as any other value when selected in A. I can not change SQL query.

Comment: what is the special character? Does A and B have any releation at database level

Comment: Special Character is square bracket [ ], Although I have tested with other special characters. They seems to be working fine but only square bracket giving issue.

Comment: Yes, A and B have a key linked together. Also I have modified my sql query (which I never wanted to do) where I replace [ ]  with ( ) and than while printing report I have used original A name. But this do not give me the exact solution. Its just the work around. Also I was thinking if crystal report internally understand [ ] as an array and that's why whole trouble start....